# Directx accessing backbuffer

Tags: c++, directx, buffer

I am trying to access the screen data from backbuffer using directx. However with the code below, the pointer to the pixel data has all 0.
I am really not sure if I am checking the data correctly. I am running this on Visual studio 2013, and using break points to check the pointer `b`. And its value is 0, all the time. 
I am aware that I am not using `IDirect3DDevice9::GetRenderTargetData` method. This cause me to try to access the data in the device's memory I suppose. Would it prevent me from getting correct pixel data ?

```
d3dManager = new D3DManager(NULL, 600, 600);
    IDirect3DDevice9 *device = d3dManager->getDevice();
    IDirect3DSurface9 *ppBackBuffer = NULL;
    HRESULT result = device->GetBackBuffer(
        0,
        0,
        D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,
        &ppBackBuffer
    );

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        printf("vuhu");
        return 1;
    }

    D3DSURFACE_DESC pDesc;
    ppBackBuffer->GetDesc(&pDesc);
    HANDLE *handle = NULL;
    device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(pDesc.Width, pDesc.Height, pDesc.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &ppBackBuffer, handle);


    D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRectangle;
    ppBackBuffer->LockRect(&lockedRectangle, NULL, D3DLOCK_DONOTWAIT);
    void* bits = lockedRectangle.pBits;
    int *a = (int*)(bits);
    int *b = a + 120;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface` here, and you pass in ppBackBuffer, it gets overwritten because it's creating  new surface that's empty by default. In fact, you just leaked your reference to the backbuffer you obtained from `GetBackBuffer`.

```
 D3DSURFACE_DESC pDesc;
 ppBackBuffer->GetDesc(&pDesc);
 HANDLE *handle = NULL;
 device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(pDesc.Width, pDesc.Height, pDesc.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &ppBackBuffer, handle);
```

You need to actually call `GetRenderTargetData` to copy the data from the backbuffer (which is likely in video memory that is completely inaccessible to the CPU) to a surface you can read from the CPU.

BTW, check the HRESULTs of your calls, particularly `CreateOffscreenPlainSurface` and `LockRect`.

**EDIT:** If what you mean to do is create a new surface with the same properties as the backbuffer, then you should do:

```
D3DSURFACE_DESC pDesc;
ppBackBuffer->GetDesc(&pDesc);
ppBackBuffer->Release(); // <--- Let go of our reference to the back buffer surface
HANDLE *handle = NULL;
device->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(pDesc.Width, pDesc.Height, pDesc.Format, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &ppBackBuffer, handle);
```

There's nothing at all in your code that is actually moving the contents of the back buffer into the new surface. You are just reusing the variable `IDirect3DSurface9 *ppBackBuffer`.

Comment: Sorry but isnt ppBackBuffer supposed to be overwritten by CreateOffscreenPlainSurface, as the method is supposed to fill it ?

Comment: You call ``GetBackBuffer`` and it returns a COM object pointer to the back buffer surface. You *then* call ``CreateOffscreenPlainSurface`` which creates a new surface and returns a COM object pointer clobbering the original COM object pointer to the back buffer surface. In other words, the only thing you accomplished by calling ``GetBackBuffer`` was to increase the reference count by 1 after getting the properties.